# Unable to search the non english character in google search appliance (GSA)

Tags: search-engine, google-search-appliance

We are using google search appliance product in our application. We have added the non English character in Frontend->Keymatch. When we are searching from our site, no result found error page is displayed.

Kindly suggest us to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by saying non english character, you meant the accented characters.
GSA can retrun keymatch results for query terms with accented characters if the query is encoded properly. Encode your query and added ie request parameter with appropriate encoding value.
You can read more about ie and other request parameters [here](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html).

You should have added some sample keymatch entry which you configured that would have helped to assist you effectively.